# Update rest request data based on the previous step response data

Tags: json, rest, groovy, soapui

I’m learning about test automation and I try to use a response values as the next request input. The problem is that the response includes a list that can have any number of elements.

The code looks like this:

Response:

```
{
   "idNumber": null,
   "response":    {
      "event": "7b-34g",
      "products":       [
                  {
            "id": "3464",
            "productName": "Hats"
         },
                  {
            "id": "3465",
            "productName": "Shoes"
         }
      ]
   },
   "errors": null
}
```

Next Request:

```
{
    "customer": "000011223333",
    "payment": "visa",
    "zzzz": "012345678-9",
    "products": [{
        "id": ""
        }],
    "XXXX": {
        "YYYY": {
            "profile": "Consumer"
            }
        }
    }
```

The number of elements in products is arbitrary, i.e., it can be any number of elements. I tried with groovy script but could not find out how to do it. I only need the “products” list from the response and from each element I only need the “id”. The rest of the values is static.
I’m thankful for any help
//Mikael

Comment: In the next request, do you need only id? both id and name are required?

Comment: Only the id in the request

Comment: Thank you Mikael for the confirmation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the `Script Assertion` for the first request test step.

The below script does:

- reads the current response
- extracts products details
- reads the next step(user needs to provide the next step name where you want the new request to be set)
- update the `products` details
- modify the next step request with updated data

```groovy
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder

//Provide the name of the next request test step name where you need to override the content
def nextStepName = 'step2'

//DO NOT REQUIRE TO MODIFY 
//Check the current step response
assert context.response, 'Response is empty'

def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(context.response)
def products = json.response.products
log.info "Products details from current response: $products"

//Get the next test step request
def nextStepRequest = context.testCase.testSteps[nextStepName].httpRequest

//Check if the next step request content is empty
assert nextStepRequest.requestContent, "Next step, $nextStepName, request is empty"

def slurped = new JsonSlurper().parseText(nextStepRequest.requestContent)
def builder = new JsonBuilder(slurped)

//Change the products of next request
builder.content.products = products.inject([]){l, item -> def map = [:];map['id'] = item.id; l << map; l}

//Update the product details in the request
nextStepRequest.requestContent = builder.toPrettyString()
log.info "Updated request for the step ${nextStepName} is : ${nextStepRequest.requestContent}"
```

You can quickly try this online <kbd>[Demo](https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5136269650690048)</kbd>

The above script assumes the names of the test step is `step2` in the below statement of the script. If it is different in your case, please change the value.

```
def nextStepName = 'step2'
```

Comment: Wow thank you! Works perfect. This will be well used!

Comment: @Mikael, glad that it is helpful.

Comment: @Mikael, appreciate if you can up vote the helpful answers.

Comment: I tried to do it before but didn't have the functionality but I just got enough reputation to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Given a list of products:

```
​products = [[id:123, name:'alpha'], [id:456, name:'beta']]
```

You can get a list with just the IDs this way:

```
products.collect{[id: it.id]}​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Comment: Thank you but I know how to get the list but I don't know how to use it in the next request since the number of elements varies. I want to do this as a part of a testsuite.

Comment: OK that only answers the second part of `I only need the “products” list from the response and from each element I only need the “id”`. Can you show what you have tried so far?